# Jurabib does not show all authors in bibliography

Tags: author-number, jurabib

I have an issue with my bibliography. It only shows up to two authors in the bibliography and then switches over to et al.

I learned that jurabib is somewhat limited in its abilities. Switching over to bibtex or anything else is however out of the question by now.

The jurabib setup I use can be seen here (it is taken from somewhere - I don't remember where):

```
    \jurabibsetup{
    commabeforerest,
    ibidem=strict,
    citefull=first,
    see,
    titleformat={colonsep,all},
}
```

Does anyone know a quick way of changing it so that it uses the et al. option only in `\footcite` "mode" and displays all authors in the bibliography?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you will have to modify the `.bst` file.

Find `jurabib.bst`, copy it to somewhere TeX can find it and rename it to, say `jurabib-all.bst`.

Then open the file and search for lines containing

```
%%% change '#3' for other et al. behavior
```

and

```
%%% change '#3' for other et al. behavior in citation
```

immediately after those lines you will find something like `#3 >` or `numnames #3 >`, there change the `#3` to whatever you want (to show all authors a ridiculous high number such as `#999` does the job). If I counted correctly you will have about eight lines, of which two are for citations, the other six are for the bibliography.

You can even change the cite and bibliography behaviour independently.

Save the file and use `\bibliographystyle{jurabib-all}` in your document.

Comment: More specifically, change line 731 to `{ numnames #99 >` and line 742 to `numnames #99 > or`. Then you will get all the authors listed in your bibliography.